# Using Wordcram on server side

Tags: processing, tag-cloud, word-cloud

The only WordCram constructor uses PApplet. Does it mean there is no server-side use?
Is any example available for server side exporting png file?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make WordCram. I get this question a lot.

There's no way to make Processing sketches run without an applet, and that means no WordCrams, either.